# Google C++ style guide on members of a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, google-style-guide

The Google C++ style guide states [in the section about inheritance](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Inheritance) that:

> Limit the use of protected to those member functions that might need to be accessed from subclasses. Note that [data members should be private](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Access_Control).

Consider now the following case:

```
class A {
    private:
         double m;
    // ...
}

class B : public A {
    // ...
}
```

I guess the correct approach is that class A implements getter/setter functions for m such that class B can access it?

I don't really get why this rule has been chosen instead of using `protected` for data members as well. Could someone explain?

Comment: It's probably off-topic because primarily opinion based, but [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOCElcMcFik) probably has the most relevant opinion in this case and explains why you should not follow the google style guide.

Comment: dont confuse what the google style guide suggests with "the correct approach". What might be appropriate for a millions lines code base with lots of old code is not necessarily the best for your project

Comment: Adding getters and setters defeats the purpose of hiding the representation. The "correct" approach is to design `A` so that `B` doesn't need to be aware that `m` exists.